# HTTPService in Flex with multiconnections

Tags: apache-flex, httpservice

I am using an `HTTPService` in my Flex application. I want to load several xml files, each about 1mb in size. Sometimes I need to stop loading previous xml file and start loading a new one. If I use `HTTPService.cancel();` or `HTTPService.disconnect()` , it increase the time to get the answer from the server.

Is there a quick way to stop the previous loading in `HTTPService` and start new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the reasoning for using one HTTPService request object to load several XML Documents? It seems to me that using multiple HTTPService objects would be the better solution as they make their requests asynchronously.

If the order they are loaded matters, then you may need to build some kind of queueing mechanism or chain the requests so they happen in the correct order without having to cancel the pending request...